# On Rules Event Present Splash Screen To Flagged User

Tags: rules, flags

Hello i was wondering what would be the best path to take to achieve my goal. I am working on a website. I am using Rules and Flag modules. I was hoping to set up a rule that when a member has been flagged then an event would happen that would be like a big cartoon splash YOUVE BEEN FLAGGED (with an image and maybe possibly sound)

Im sure that this could be within the scope of drupal. Could anyone suggest a possible way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way is define your own Rules action against on that event.

Check the api: (assuming you are using D7)

http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!rules.api.php/function/hook_rules_action_info/7

Use jQuery to pop up an alert or whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks gilzero. Ive been caught up with other things on my site for a while to worry about how to make big farty noises on it lol. Im using D6 gilzero. I think youve pretty much answered my question for me. I know ive a lot of questions to ask within but i think your solution would be the way to go. I have Rules installed there and i use it minimally for now. I will return to this.